# Winbind / AD - changed user account issue

Tags: centos, samba, administration, active-directory, winbind

So here's an odd one. We've had a user for years who happens to have a user id by local convention that matches a system account. So of course, I changed the users user ID in AD to avoid issues and security problems. However, having done so, some systems do not properly reflect the change, even a day later. Alarmingly, id username shows the old username with the correct id. The user is, of course, unable to log into this system. Even chown user:group on his home directory reflects the old user id. Anyone ever run into this before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, as it turns out, winbind's cache was stale. I'm not sure how to set that to refresh more often, which is what I would prefer for a solution, but I found that the following was effective in fixing the issue:

```
Note: This is a CentOS 5.x system. Adjust as necessary for your OS.

/sbin/service winbind stop
/sbin/service smb stop
/usr/bin/net cache flush
/bin/rm -f /var/lib/samba/*.tdb
/bin/rm -f /var/lib/samba/group_mapping.ldb
/sbin/service smb start
/sbin/service winbind start
```

Run as root, or preface with sudo.

Comment: I'm curious... Are you using `nscd` as well? Either way, did you try `net cache flush` from the affected host?